# Symfony 5 - find(ELEMENT) doesn't work (?) in delete function (CRUD)

Tags: php, symfony

I try to create my first API in Symfony. I have a little problem with my Delete function.

My entity class:

```
<?php

namespace App\Entity;

use App\Repository\InFlowsRepository;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;


/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass=InFlowsRepository::class)
 */
class InFlows
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    public int $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
     */
    public string $inFlowName;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="float")
     */
    public float $inFlowValue;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string")
     */
    public String $inFlowsDate;

    public function getId(): ?int
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    public function getInFlowName(): ?string
    {
        return $this->inFlowName;
    }

    public function setInFlowName(string $inFlowName): self
    {
        $this->inFlowName = $inFlowName;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getInFlowValue(): ?float
    {
        return $this->inFlowValue;
    }

    public function setInFlowValue(float $inFlowValue): self
    {
        $this->inFlowValue = $inFlowValue;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getInFlowsDate(): ?String
    {
        return $this->inFlowsDate;
    }

    public function setInFlowsDate(String $inFlowsDate): self
    {
        $this->inFlowsDate = $inFlowsDate;

        return $this;
    }
}
```

And my Delete controller:

```
     /**
     * @Route("inflows/delete/", name="delete_inflow")
     * @throws Exception
     */
    public function inFlowDelete(Request $id): JsonResponse {

        try {
            $repo = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
            $inflows = $repo->getRepository(InFlows::class)->find($id);
            if (!$inflows) {
                throw new \JsonException("There is no data to delete!");
            }
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            return new JsonResponse(["data"=>$e->getMessage()]);
        }
        $repo->remove($inflows);
        $repo->flush();

        return new JsonResponse("Success!");
    }
```

When I run my script I get an error:

```
An exception occurred while executing \u0027SELECT t0.id AS id_1, t0.in_flow_name AS in_flow_name_2, t0.in_flow_value AS in_flow_value_3, t0.in_flows_date AS in_flows_date_4 FROM in_flows t0 WHERE t0.id = ?\u0027 with params [{\u0022attributes\u0022:{},\u0022request\u0022:{},\u0022query\u0022:{},\u0022server\u0022:{},\u0022files\u0022:{},\u0022cookies\u0022:{},\u0022headers\u0022:{}}]:\n\nSQLSTATE[22P02]: Invalid text representation: 7 ERROR: invalid input syntax for type integer: \u0022DELETE \/inflows\/delete\/?id=1 HTTP\/1.1\r\nAccept: *\/*\r\nAccept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br\r\nCache-Control: no-cache\r\nConnection: keep-alive\r\nContent-Length: \r\nContent-Type: \r\nHost: 127.0.0.1:8000\r\nMod-Rewrite: On\r\nPostman-Token: 6f77209a-8bad-4109-93a8-4c43647d7849\r\nUser-Agent: PostmanRuntime\/7.28.0\r\nX-Php-Ob-Level: 1\r\n\r\n\u0022e2
```

I don't have idea why my instruction "where t0.id = ?" looks like.
Why my "find($id)" function doesn't work?
Is the way to fix it out?

Thanks for response.

Comment: You pass a `Request` object to `find`. That's probably not what you want to do.

Comment: @nikoshr
But the `Request` object is an element (id) from user. I pass this element to my find function where the Result is the `object`. This object is the param to remove function. 
Is not correct?
I can't pass my refactor delete function but now when I pass find(['id' => $id] get another error: 
`Cannot assign null to property App\Entity\InFlows::$id of type int (500 Internal Server Error)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I know what's the problem, here your input is a Request (httpd request ) which contains a lot of informationu can  check this in your browser , anyway so the best solution is to pass the id as an argument and delee it like this :
/**
* @Route("inflows/delete/{id}", name="delete_inflow")
* @throws Exception
*/
public function inFlowDelete(int $id): JsonResponse {

```
    try {
        $repo = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $inflows = $repo->getRepository(InFlows::class)->find($id);
        if (!$inflows) {
            throw new \JsonException("There is no data to delete!");
        }
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        return new JsonResponse(["data"=>$e->getMessage()]);
    }
    $repo->remove($inflows);
    $repo->flush();

    return new JsonResponse("Success!");
}
```

try it and keep me updated !

Comment: Your solution is the same that I implement in my code and it works perfect. I don't know why I put request ID in my function arg. 
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

```
/**
 * @Route("inflows/delete/{id}", name="delete_inflow")
 */
public function inFlowDelete(InFlows $inFlows): JsonResponse {
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    $em->remove($inFlows);
    $em->flush();

    return new JsonResponse("Success!");
}
```

Comment: It doesn't work - I get this error: `Cannot assign null to property App\Entity\InFlows::$id of type int`

Comment: You should add `null`  for the `id` property in the entity. Example `public ?int $id=null;`.  Because the doctrine sets null for ID after delete.

Answer (score 0):

I think that the problem is that u didn't use persist , when u act on the data base u have to persist your changement so it'll look like
/**
* @Route("inflows/delete/", name="delete_inflow")
* @throws Exception
*/
public function inFlowDelete(Request $id): JsonResponse {

```
    try {
        $repo = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $inflows = $repo->getRepository(InFlows::class)->find($id);
        if (!$inflows) {
            throw new \JsonException("There is no data to delete!");
        }
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        return new JsonResponse(["data"=>$e->getMessage()]);
    }
    $repo->remove($inflows);
    $repo->persist();
    $repo->flush();

    return new JsonResponse("Success!");
}
```

if i can give you an advice dont use remove() because it'll remove physically your row , somtimes it's better to remove logically , so use setDeletedAt(new \Datetime());

Comment: Thanks for your share. Unfortunately your solution doesn't work. I still have the same error as before.

Answer (score 0):

So I delete my table and create new migration files. My code was still the same which I posted in @nikoshr solution. And It works ! Very strange but as they say - darkest under the lantern.